# Prevent from doing decimals

Tags: matlab

I am summing numbers between two indices in a matrix, like this: `ans = sum(my_matrix1x500(100:300));`

The `ans` then is a number like: *351267300.4473* and so on. How do I prevent it from printing the decimals? Instead of *351267300.4473* it could print *3512673004473* or simply remove the decimal, is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the answer to *display* as an integer or actually be an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fprintf('%.0f',X)` to print X with '0' significant digits, or `round(X)` to remove the decimal altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an arbitrary number of decimal places this is not gonna work easily, since the number usually has many more decimal places than it shows. Read the [discussion here](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/116017).

But if you know how many decimal places you want to keep, you simply write:

```
p = 4 % number of decimal places to keep
ans = floor(ans * 10 ^ p);
```

This gives you the desired **numerical value**.